# How to retrieve POST parameters sent via AJAX with C#?

Tags: c#, webview2

I have a simple C# application that uses a `WebView` that is loading a small html form that is hosted locally.

The form has two fields, such as: Name and E-mail. It is a button that, when pressed, calls a javascript function that takes all the values of the existing fields in the form, and which must be sent back to C#.

So that later I can save them in the local database or maybe send them to an online server.

```
var form= $("#formId");
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'HOW CAN I SEND BACK TO C#?',
    data: form.serialize(),
    success: function (data) {
      console.log('HOW C# CAN RESPOND BACK?');
    }
});
```

Is it possible for C# to receive this ajax request under the hood? If not, what are the other ways to retrieve these form fields with C# once the user clicks the submit button?

Comment: @rbdeenk send to a C# class, you mean? Since I'm using WinForms and not ASP.NET (MVC).

Comment: I see, I misinterpreted the question. If i understand correctly you want to send the data to the C# backend on form submit? Could you maybe share a screenshot of the view?

Comment: @rbdeenk yes I want to send the data to the C# backend on form submit.

Comment: It would be really beneficial if you could show your form in the form of a screenshot. I'm afraid I can't help you if i don't see how you setup your program

Comment: a form can have an attribute asp-action="<actionName>" and asp-controller="<controllerName>" and then inside ajax u put parameters url and method like this:
$.ajax({
                    url: form.attr("action"),
                    method: form.attr("method"),

Comment: @SudoSur the WebView2 component has events that capture requests. Check [Using the WebView control to capture HTTP Request Content](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2021/Aug/18/Using-the-WebView-control-to-capture-Request-Content)

Comment: There is also the CoreWebView2.WebMessageReceived event which can be raised from script by calling window.chrome.webview.postMessage(...) to post things from script to the native code which may or may not be easier depending on what sort of form data you have.